# Converting an observable object from a web service to an array - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, mapping, observable, http-get

This project attempts to get data from a web service(which is in xml format) and map it to a project object with name, id, description etc. I have used a a service to get and map the data.

As you can see when I run my app, I can expand the Project array and the array is full of objects. I try to display this array in the HTML file but since it is not an array of objects, it doesn't let me.

[image]
The error I am getting in the console when running:

***ProjectViewerComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.***

How do I convert my list of observables(??) to an array in this case? My code is below:

**EDIT: Now getting this when I run it after updating my code(See below) in the fetchProjects method in the project.viewer.component**

[image]

project.model.ts:

```
export class Project {
    project_id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;

    constructor(obj: any) {
        this.project_id = obj.project_id;
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.description = obj.description;
    }
}
```

project.service.ts:

```
export abstract class ProjectService {
    //methods
    abstract fetchProjects(): Observable<Project[]>;
}
```

project.service.http.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectServiceHttp extends ProjectService {

    //variables
    baseUrl = "http://dev-teamcity:8090/guestAuth/app/rest/projects";

    //constructor
   constructor(private http: Http) {
        super();
    }

    //methods
    fetchProjects(): Observable<any>{
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
          .map((response: Response) => 
          {
            return response.json();
          })
          .catch(this.handleError);
        }


        private handleError(error: any) {
            // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
            // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
            let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
            console.log(errMsg); // log to console instead
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
        }

}
```

project.viewer.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'project-viewer',
    templateUrl: './project-viewer.html',  
    styleUrls: ['./project-viewer.css']
})

export class ProjectViewerComponent  {
    name = 'ProjectViewerComponent';
    projects: Project[];
    errorMessage = "";
    stateValid = true;

    constructor(private service: ProjectService) {
        this.fetchProjects();
    }

    private fetchProjects() {
        this.service
            .fetchProjects()
            .subscribe(response =>{
              this.projects = response['project'];
              console.log(response);
            },
            errors=>{
               console.log(errors);
            });
    }

    private raiseError(text: string): void {
        this.stateValid = false;
        this.errorMessage = text;
    }
}
```

project-viewer.html:

```
<h3>Projects </h3>

<div >
    <ul class= "grid grid-pad">
        <a *ngFor="let project of projects" class="col-1-4">
            <li class ="module project" >
                <h4 tabindex ="0">{{project.project_id}}</h4>
            </li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your response object contains count, href and project array. You should assign to projects project array: this.projects = response.project.

Comment: `this.projects = response.json();` should fix the issue and Add the `| async` at the end of your *ngFor

Comment: @lingthe If i try do this.projects = response.project in the fetchProjects method in the component class, it gives me" Property 'project' does not exist on type 'Project[]'"

Comment: than you should write it like this : this.projects  = response['project'],Please let me know how it went.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan the error: [ts] Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Project[]'. when I try to implement that??

Comment: Can you give us one example of project object from projects array? Or you can log it in console, projects array.

Comment: @lingthe one object when i expand the project array in the console :
{id: "_Root", name: "<Root project>", description: "Contains all other projects", href: "/guestAuth/app/rest/projects/id:_Root", webUrl: "http://dev-teamcity:8090/project.html?projectId=_Root"}

Comment: I see that you logged response. Can you log this.projects? console.log(this.projects)

Comment: Its now displaying each of my objects !

Comment: You don't have project_id property: {{project.project_id}} should be {{project.id}}

Comment: @lingthe just realised that. Thanks!

Comment: @lingthe what would be the best way to filter either the http get service where it gets the projects or the array that has been returned - to only include 9 of them? I have the specific 9 IDs that I want returned and displayed instead of them all?

Comment: You should do that in fetchProjects function - if you want first 9 than use response['project'].splice(0, 9) but if you want specific 9 then you should first make an array of that nine ids and than create function that will go trough projects and in this.projects push only objects with sutable id. Use for each for projects and compare each id from projects with id from array.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

**project.service.ts**

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
    baseUrl = "http://dev-teamcity:8090/guestAuth/app/rest/projects";
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    fetchProjects(): Observable<any> {
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) });
        return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options).map((res: Response) => {
            const jsonResponse = res.json();
            return jsonResponse;
        });
    }
}
```

**project.viewer.component.ts**

```
export class ProjectViewerComponent  {

    private projects: any;
    constructor(private service: ProjectService) { }

    this.service.fetchProjects().subscribe(data => {
        this.projects = data;
    })
}
```

in html file

```
<div>{{projects | json}}</div>
```

Comment: it cant reach the service because it is not inside the constructor?
[ts] Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.